# Obtain RSSI from bluetooth adapter Raspberry3

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, rssi, raspberry-pi3

I need to know how I can obtain de REAL RSSI from a non-connected bluetooth device with my RPi3.

I know there is a program named bluetoothctl which I don't know how it works, I can't find anything about how it works bluetootctl. But when I used it, I can obtain ALL the REAL RSSI of ALL the bluetooth devices, only with a scanning. (scan on)

I do this.

1) bluetoothctl 
 
2) scan on 
(you will obtain something like this: "Device XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX RSSI: -48" )

It's so simple, but, the problem, it's that I need to work with this data, I am not able to get this data to process later. So I need some code, in c++(better) to do this.

I know hcitool, but you have to be connected and they not give you data until you are at a distance. I can't understand how it works **bluetoothctl**

I try to do a redirect of the output to a log but...I am not able to do that..because when you put on temrinal **bluetoothctl** it happens this:

---

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ bluetoothctl

[NEW] Controller B8:27:EB:90:E8:79 raspberrypi [default]

[bluetooth]#

---

now, you can use all the commands of bluetoothctl

Thanks ;)

Comment: The [bluetoothctl source code](https://github.com/r10r/bluez/tree/master/client) is freely available. Read that if you want to understand how it does it. The summary is that bluez exports a DBUS interface. You can use that to scan for devices and read device properties.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [source](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/) as kaylum said.

You will find in doc folder hci and dbus documentation.

You can also take the bluetoothctl source (available in the folder client) and make a wrapper around it to your needs. It uses the dbus library helper developed in gdbus folder.

Answer (score 1):

you can see the rssi value using `hcidump [-a]` command but make sure to keep Bluetooth on in background , so u can just start scanning like you usually do in Bluetoothctl and then Scan on ,leave that in background and on a new command line use the hcidump command This might help you.See this also : http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/hcidump8.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following, from the command line

`sudo btmon |grep RSSI & 
sudo hcitool scan`

Or if you want to use python you can use the [inquiry with rssi](https://github.com/karulis/pybluez/blob/master/examples/advanced/inquiry-with-rssi.py) example found in the pybluez module.

Another option would be to use the DeviceDiscoverer skeleton class found in this [example](https://github.com/karulis/pybluez/blob/master/examples/simple/asynchronous-inquiry.py) and then adjust to your own needs. The device discovered function is passed the rssi which can be stored and manipulated to suit.